# TDS NOMAD windows CE5.0 device connects more than two USB devices

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce, usb-drive, activesync

I have a TDS Nomad running windows CE 5.0 system.  It has a USB host port. I have connected to the manufacture and ask if nomad can connect to more than 1 USB devices via USB hub (can connect to 7 USB devices, designed for windows ), they said they haven't tested to connect more than one USB device. If more than one devices is connected to nomad, there mightbe resource conflict.
The nomad works well with one USB device connect to it individually.
But I have a console application debugging in nomad using visual studio2005 and active sync.
I need to talk to both USB devices. Therefore I have to use USB hub. But it doesn't work most of the time. I think the drivers of two USB devices are all correctly installed on nomad.

But what I want to ask, is that has anyone tried to connect more than one USB device to windows CE product via USB hub and both of them works well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused. here.  You say the device has USB host and you want to connect more than one client device through a hub.  This is definitely supported by the OS, and I've done this with several devices from several manufacturers, though never with a Nomad.  Not sure what the OEM is talking about with "resource conflicts" as the USB spec itself allows for multiple devices (kind of the whole point behind a "bus").

But you say that your second "device" is the debugger.  That isn't a USB Host connection from the device perspective, that's a USB Client connection, and it typically uses completely different hardware and drivers for that connection.  Can a device have both a host and a client connection?  Again, yes I've done this with many devices (but not a Nomad) and the OS fully supports it.

Now maybe this is USB OTG hardware (though back in the 5.0 days I doubt it) and the OEM didn't do the design well to handle a client and a host at the same time.  Maybe the physical hardware is laid out poorly or the OAL portion of their USB driver is poorly done and can't route properly through a hub properly (I've definitely seen that before).  Hard to say.

A USB Analyzer would tell you a whole lot about what's actually happening and where the problem is, but it is definitely a supported scenario by both the USB spec and the OS.  If it's failing, it's a manufacturer/device-specific problem.

Comment: Hi @ctacke   thank you for your analysis, I just reboot the Nomad and install all the drivers again, and now it works very well.. It might be the driver problems..